# I need to generate a list by cross referencing two other datasets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm very new to trying to code and I've got a problem that has completely defeated my fledgling VBA skills. I need to take a list of recent hires and cross reference it with a list of all employees with errors, then use that data to generate a list of new hires with errors.

The script has to check and see if a recent hire is on the error list, then check to see if the error is "closed" or "closedfb" in the Close State column. If the error is "closedfb", it needs to display their login, name, manager and the number of errors, in that order, on a new list. The hitch is that a given employee may appear multiple times on the errors list.

The data sets with the new employees and errors are set up as follows:

The first sheet is titled New_Employee_List

```
:Employee Login: :Employee Name: :other data: :Start Date (column 7): :Manager Login:
         X             X               X                 X                   X
         X             X               X                 X                   X
         X             X               X                 X                   X
```

The second sheet is titled Errors_Raw_Data

```
:unused data: :Close State (column 5): :Employee (6):  :Number:
      X              X          X         X
      X              X          X         X
      X              X          X         X
```

Here is what I've tried so far, starting with a bit of code I found online. 
    Sub FPS_Macro()
    Dim NSName As String 'New Start Names
    Dim Found As Boolean

```
Range("Sherlock_Raw_Data!H2").Select 'First line of data

NSName = Summary_Report!B2 'Search variable value

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) 'Loop until cell is empty
    If ActiveCell.Value = NSName Then
        Found = True
        Exit Do
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

If Found = True Then 'Check for Found
    NewStartFPS!A2 = ActiveCell
End If

End Sub
```

I'd started with just trying to get the code to run through the one sheet and find if there were matching names on the other sheet. Unfortunately the above code returns the following error.

```
Run time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed
```

Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to make an effort to do this on your own. We generally don't write code for you, but rather help you address specific problems you're running into. To get started, you'll want to take a look at the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). If you get stuck, edit your question to include what code you've tried.

Comment: Apologies, I was in a bit of a hurry as I wrote this. I've edited my question with what I had tried, and what error I was getting. Thanks.